# Dynamically create <li> element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following on html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../3003_Testing/js/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../3003_Testing/js/search.js"></script>
<title>Search Box</title>
    <link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<section class="main">
     <form class="search" >
         <input id="searchAddress" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search address" oninput="getAddress()" />
         <ul class="results" id="addressList">
         <li id="staticli"><a href="index.html">Static li element<br><span>This is a Static li element</span></a></li>
         </ul>   
     </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get write a function to handle the event when any of the list element get clicked. But it doesn't seems to be triggering at all when I click on the `<li>` element.

```
$('#addressList').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert("clicked");
    alert( $(this).text() );

});
```

The `<li>` elements are created dynamically through this code:

```
listContents = $("<li id=\"" + i + "\"><a href=\"index.html\">" + addresses[i].lable + "</a></li>");
jQuery('#addressList').append(listContents);
```

And I verified through my browser's console that they are being created correctly as such

```
outerHTML: "<li id="0"><a href="index.html">6 Cashew Crescent<br><span>6 Cashew Crescent. (S)679751</span></a></li>"
```

**Let's ignore about the dynamic list first. The thing is even my static list element are not responding to the event handler upon click.** Have been trying to figure out the problem for a couple of hours now..

I have created a jsfiddle for my static li element not working https://jsfiddle.net/tmu50t9z/

jsfiddle to my whole code > https://jsfiddle.net/8wwnx64x/

Comment: can you make a demo/fiddle please ?

Comment: What you have shown here works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/43qwc38r/. Please check the console for errors in your version.

Comment: @John I am not sure how do you link the `jquery.js` on fiddle but you can see most of code on my update post.

Comment: And make sure #addressList is unique.

Comment: You need to do preventdefault. otherwise the same page will be reloaded since the target is anchor.

Comment: Yes #addressList is unique and there were no errors generated on my console when I clicked on the list element.

Comment: Tried all the answers, but oddly it's not triggering still. Could it be that my `.css` is messing with it? Sorry am new to web development

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addressList li').on('click', function() {
    alert("clicked");
    alert( $(this).text() );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Work code, try this

HTML

```
<ul class="results" id='addressList'> </ul>
<button  id="aaa">Add LI</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var a=0;
$('#aaa').click(function() {
 $('#addressList').append('<li id="'+a+'"><a href="index.html">6 Cashew     Crescent<br><span>6 Cashew Crescent. (S)679751</span></a></li>');
 a++
});
$( "#addressList" ).on( "click", "li", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: I just tried this piece of code and added a static `<li>` element on the HTML itself. The static element which was already there would not be under the effect of the function. So it might be that my `<li>` was not created dynamically? I am not very sure why but I created them on javascript.